# JQuery Change Event for InnerHTML

Tags: innerhtml, jquery

In my case i'm writing a Chrome Extension, I don't have access to the other JS that is happening on the page.  So I need to make sure that whenever certain elements update their content I rerun a function from the extension.

Basically a Change event that can be triggered from innerHTML changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's for a Chrome extension, might as well the standard [DOM Mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents).

Listen to `DOMSubtreeModified` on the `document`. Just tested on Chrome 5.0.375.99 and it is supported.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', myFunction);
```

Comment: This works great in my Safari and Chrome Extension.  Thank you.  However it does not work in a greasemonkey version of the same script, any ideas?